# Using Python to re-write my code from 'readlines' to 'for line in file' format

Tags: python

I have a working script to extract certain data from a series of huge text files.  Unfortunately I went down the route of 'readlines' and consequently my code is running out of memory after a certain number of files processed.

I am try to re-write my code to process the files line by line using the 'for line in file' format, but I am now having problems with my line processing once a string is found.

Basically once my string is found I hope to go to various surrounding lines in the text file, so I am hoping to go back to say 16 (and 10 and 4) lines before and do some line processing to collect some associated data to the search line.  With the readlines route I enumerated the file, but I am struggling to work out the correct method with a line by line method (or find out indeed if it is even possible!).

Here's my code, I'll admit I have some bad code in there as I have played about a bit with the line grabbing, basically around the line[-xx] parts...

```
searchstringsFilter1 = ['Filter Used          : 1']


with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:

        timestampline = None
        timestamp = None

        for word in searchstringsFilter1:
            if word in line:
                #print line
                timestampline = line[-16]
                #print timestampline
                keyline = line
                Rline = line[-10]
                print Rline

                Rline = re.sub('[()]', '', Rline)   
                SNline = line[-4]
                SNline = re.sub('[()]', '', SNline) 

                split = keyline.split()
                str = timestampline
                match = re.search(r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}', str)
                valueR = Rline.split()
                valueSN = SNline.split()

                split = line.split()

                worksheetFilter.write(row_num,0,match.group()) 
                worksheetFilter.write(row_num,1,split[3], integer_format)
                worksheetFilter.write(row_num,2,valueR[4], decimal_format)
                worksheetFilter.write(row_num,3,valueSN[3], decimal_format)
                row_num+=1
                tot = tot+1
                break

    print 'total count for', '"',searchstringsFilter1[a],'"', 'is', tot
    Filtertot = tot
    tot = 0
```

Is there anything obvious I am doing wrong, or am I following a completely incorrect path to do what I am trying to do?

Many thanks for reading this,
MikG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) to temporarly hold the previous line in memory. This can be obtained using `collections.deque` :

```
import collections

ring_buf = collections.deque(maxlen=17)

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        ring_buf.append([line]) # append the new line and overwrite the last one
                              # FIFO style

        timestampline = None
        timestamp = None

        for word in searchstringsFilter1:
            if word in line:
                #print line
                timestampline = ring_buf[-16]
                #print timestampline
                keyline = line
                Rline = ring_buf[-10]
                print Rline

                Rline = re.sub('[()]', '', Rline)   
                SNline = ring_buf[-4]
                SNline = re.sub('[()]', '', SNline)
```

Comment: Thanks georgesl, It looks to be what I am looking for.  Just having a few problems posting to my xlsx file at the moment, i'm getting error... TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number..., but the lines captured are in order.

Answer (score 3):

If you know how many lines you need to use at a time (let's say that you need 16 lines at a time), you can do this:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    # Some sort of loop...
    chunk = [next(f) for x in xrange(16)]
```

`chunk` should contain the next 16 lines of the file.

---

EDIT: after some clarification, this might be more useful:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    chunk = [next(f) for x in xrange(16)]

    while not whatWeWant(chunk[15]):
        chunk.append(next(f))
        chunk.pop(0)
```

Obviously, this would need some guards and checks, but I think this is what you want. chunk[15] will be the line you were trying to find, and chunk[0:15] will be the lines before it.

Comment: Thanks Tom, that's useful to know.  Is this only for the following 16 lines of text (rather than the previous 16 lines) once the string is found?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. I suppose that you could make a 'moving chunk' by starting with this, then having a loop that adds the next line (`chunk.append(next(f))`) and removes the first line (`chunk.pop(0)`) until chunk[15] is what you're looking for. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I think @georgesl has a more elegant answer, though :)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I think I'll stick with @georgesl answer, but you have provided me with some additional information in your answer which will be useful for one of my other scripts once I start the readlines conversion...it's a shame I can't accept TWO answers!  :)